# Are the dynamic arrays in DOORS data base worth using?

Tags: database, arrays, ibm-doors

I am a new developer for a DOORS database and I'm writing scripts in dxl.
As you know there are 1-dimensional arrays in dxl. I wanted to use more than one dimension so I decided to use a dynamic array, but this slowed my script down a lot, and when we have around 14,000 objects per module it would take a day or so for the script to run.

I was wondering if it is reasonable to use dynamic arrays in these scripts or if anyone has experience in dealing with dynamic arrays in databases?

Just curious thanks!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Dynamic arrays are considerably slower than C style arrays in DOORS, so you should avoid them if you know the size of the array beforehand.

If you know the number of elements but need more dimensions you can do it like this:

```
//Define an array of (for example) bool
int imax=5
int jmax=7
bool myarray[imax*jmax]

//Access for example element myarray[3][2]
int i=3
int j=2
bool mybool=myarray[i*jmax+j]
```

Comment: Thank you very much! And that is very interesting to treat the one dimensional arrays as 2-dimensional, I will have to give that a try.