# Perl - Is this right name for function?

Tags: perl, naming-conventions

The title say it all. I am trying to find good naming convention for my functions. Some suggestions are  [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/979118/trouble-coming-up-with-good-names-for-functions) but I would like to know your opinion and if it is possible to use shorter name and still preserve the meaning of the function. This is my function:

```
sub convert_AoA_to_HoA_where_hash_key_is_element_from_particular_inner_array_index_and_hash_value_is_reference_to_this_inner_array(){
  my ($argv1, $argv2, $argv3) = @_;
  my @AoA = @$argv1;
  my $HoA = $argv2;
  my $index = $argv3;

    foreach my $array (@AoA){
    $HoA->{"$array->[$index]"} = $array;
 }
}
```

Comment: Is your function name coming out in movie form soon? I tried to read the novelization, but I couldn't make it. Try and use something shorter.

Comment: I like the combination of incredibly verbose function name with entirely generic parameter names.

Comment: Subroutine name like that is absurd.  Keep the name as short as possible but descriptive.  Such as sub AoA2HoA {....}.  The detailed description of what it does could be a comment inside and at the beginning of the sub.

Comment: Your current name for it could just be a comment above it.

Comment: `Perl Best Practices' by Damian Conway can help you there

Comment: `sub create_keyed_recordset { my ($key_index, $recordset) = @_; return map { $_->[$index] => $_ } @$recordset }`

Answer (score 2):

If you are having to do this, this may be indicating something about the suitability of the existing data structures to begin with.

As [mpapec demonstrates](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24389492/133939), the functionality is simple enough to replicate without the need for a dedicated subroutine using `map`.

Since the keys of the resultant hash are the values of a particular column, an alternative could be to use a hash slice to clarify intent:

```
my %hash;
@hash{ map $_->[$index], @AoA } = @AoA;
```

The only time when I would consider having to roll this into a subroutine would be if I had no control over the incoming data structure and needed to output separate hashes for different indices. Having said that, `rehash_by_column_index` is a more-befitting name for such a sub.

Answer (score 2):

Without going into philosophical debate, you don't need to make it a function,

```
my %HoA = map { $_->[$index] => $_ } @AoA;
```